# strange network issue after new router 'unkownXX…' terminal promt instead of Name

Tags: terminal, network, wifi, internet, router

Some weeks ago I got a new router* and since then I encounter some local network issues from time to time (at the moment I can’t reproduce *when* this happens):

1. Wifi is connected but webpages don’t load. The page stays blank and I get *no* message about a missing network connection.
2. Accessing `tobis-mac.local` (or `http://localhost`, or `http://127.0.0.1`) is really slow or don’t load at all (same as 1). When I disable wifi (i.e. no network connection for my mac) the local host again is as fast as usual.
3. While this happens The terminal promo reads

   ```
   unkown7cd1XXXXXXXXX:~ Tobi$
   ```

   (I replaced some digits with `X` because I have no idea if this info should be kept private …) instead of the normal

   ```
   Tobis-Mac:~ Tobi$
   ```

Some setup information

- I’m using a MacBook Pro mid 2012 13" running OS X 10.11.4 (I made the update today. The described error occurred under 10.11.3, though).
- My Mac is connected via Wifi; Wifi uses 2.4 GHz only and WPA (no WPS)
- The router is the one I got from my provider, which is o2 Germany: o2 HomeBox 6641. ZyXEL Communications Corp.

I’m aware that my descriptions are rather incomplete but I am far from being an network expert so let me know if I can provide further information ;-)

Comment: btw. I would also appreciate if someone could name some relevant google search terms, because I didn’t found anything myself about this issue, cause a lack of the right key words.